# How to write a string with win32api and win32con in python 3.4.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi

Trying to create a program that acts like a real life user, so I am using win32api and win32con for mouse movements

```
import win32api, win32con

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
```

However I also want it to be able to fill out strings, I have been trying to look online but no luck, so really in short. The question is, how can I use these modules to write a string to for example an online form?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: its not an answer so ill just leave this here https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto (if you really really want to implement it from scratch for some reason https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/pywinauto/keyboard.py ... although imho madness lies there)

Comment: I can't see how this can type a string into a text box? - Sorry maybe I am missing something? Have you maybe got a code example? Thanks

Comment: Joran, I think you might be complicating what I am asking? All I need it to do is type a string out into a text box that isn't part of the Python program, e.g. info a text box on a web form for example.

Comment: Use UI Automation. Faking input is not the solution. Don't make the same mistake that so many before you have made.

Comment: David, what do you mean by this? How can I do this? - I want to fill in a 3rd party online form, but the process is very repetitive so I wish to automate it by having a system enter all the details for me.

Comment: Use UI Automation. If you don't know what that is use web search. Pywinauto would also get it done I suspect. If you don't know how to use pywinauto use web search. If you don't know how to use web search, give up.

Comment: David, iv been trying all evening :/

Comment: lol i meant to link to https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui ... its easier to use than pywinauto ... pywinauto is overkill

Comment: That's tough, but ultimately your problem. Sometimes tasks take time and beginners can have unrealistic expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pyautogui as g
g.click(x=100, y=150) # click text box
g.typewrite('Hello world!')   #type something...
g.click(x=200,y=100) # click ok
```

maybe ... this uses the third party pyautogui library

Comment: Thank you so much! <3 - needed to do "pip install pyautogui" on cmd